How do I override the base URL in the Twilio Java SDK?
I'd like to be able to use the Twilio SDK for Java in my Kotlin project, but I need to override the base URL to point at a wiremock when I'm running integration tests locally and in our deployment pipelines.
This question has already been raised, but I'm using the Verify API and the Test Credentials APIs don't support the /Verifications and /VerificationCheck endpoints.
Has anyone out there managed to solve this problem and either override the base URL or come up with some other strategy for running tests without needing to hit the actual Twilio API?
I've looked for example code in the Twilio docs, but the approach isn't well documented. As best as I can tell, I'll need to create my own instance of the TwilioRestClient with a custom HttpClient and RequestConfig.
At this point it seems easier to just write my own client for the Twilio API, which is the approach I'm taking for now.
